# Kotlin generic number Union?

Tags: generics, collections, kotlin, extension-methods

I want to implement a cumulative sum method for `List`, such a function should accept `List<Int>`, `List<Float>`, etc.

I could go as far as to say that it should accept `List<anything that implements add>`

But I see no way of specifying this in the official documentation.

I have tried using the type `Number` but it apparently does not work.

How should I go about making a generic extension function that accepts any type implementing a particular method like `add`?

Comment: How is this related to Java? Also [don't tag in title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Why you can't add numbers

Numbers only have the following methods:

- `public abstract fun toDouble(): Double`
- `public abstract fun toFloat(): Float`
- `public abstract fun toLong(): Long`
- `public abstract fun toInt(): Int`
- `public abstract fun toChar(): Char`
- `public abstract fun toShort(): Short`
- `public abstract fun toByte(): Byte`

There is no add, so you can't add them together

## Workarounds

- You can use the Iterable methods, which should be available on lists
- You can wrap the Numbers, and have the wrappers supply an add method
- You could use reflection to do this, but it might not be the best way

## Hacky casting workaround

```
typealias Adder<T> = (T)->T

fun <T: Number> T.toAdder(): Adder<T> {
    return when(this) {
        is Long -> {{it -> (this as Long + it as Long) as T}}
        is Int -> {{it -> (this as Int + it as Int) as T}}
        is Double -> {{it -> (this as Double + it as Double) as T}}
        else -> throw AssertionError()
    }
}

fun <T: Number> List<T>.mySum(zero: T): T {
    return map { it.toAdder() }.fold(zero) { acc, func -> func(acc)  }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val total = listOf(1,2,4).mySum(0)
}
```

This works, but it uses a lot of casting, and should be avoided

Comment: I see. So there is no way to impose a... contract... on the generic types you use then?

Comment: You can impose interfaces and classes, but there is no common interface or class with add, also, my answer is for normal sum, rather than cumulative

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin, you have these extension functions in the stdlib:

```
fun Iterable<Byte>.sum(): Int { /* compiled code */ }
fun Iterable<Double>.sum(): Double { /* compiled code */ }
fun Iterable<Float>.sum(): Float { /* compiled code */ }
fun Iterable<Int>.sum(): Int { /* compiled code */ }
fun Iterable<Long>.sum(): Long { /* compiled code */ }
fun Iterable<Short>.sum(): Int { /* compiled code */ }
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.sumBy(selector: (T) -> Int): Int { /* compiled code */ }
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.sumByDouble(selector: (T) -> Double): Double { /* compiled code */ }
```

And from that you can see there isn't a way to write a function for "`List` of types that have `plus` method", since Kotlin is not duck typed.

Also, you mentioned `List<anything that implements add>`, which is unclear (or, clear but incorrect), because in Kotlin, all number types have `plus` instead of `add`. From that you can know, different classes have their own definitions of the "add" operation, and such operation have different names under different circumstances.

I recommend you to use the function called `reduce`, or `reduceRight`, or `fold`, or `foldRight`, which allows you to customize your "add" operation by passing an argument.

Like, the implementation of `sum` for `List<Int>` is basically:

```
fun List<Int>.sum() = fold(0, Int::plus)
```

And the like.

Comment: Hello, I know about the `sum` method but cumulative sum is a whole other thing. A cumulative sum is a list where the `i`'th element is the sum of the first `i` elements of the initial list. For example the cumulative sum of `1 3 5 2 1` is `1 4 9 11 12`.
That is what I asked my question the way I did. Sorry but this doesn't really answer my question :/

Comment: Oh god. I've told you that there isn't a way to reuse the code among those subtypes of `Number` and use the implementation of `sum` as an example (to prove what I said is correct), but you say it's not answering your question. I assume **you're asking for an implementation of cumulative sum**, which is considered spam on SO.

Comment: No, I did not ask for that at all :/ That is simply the algorithm I was handling at the time I came across this problem/question and so I used it to give a concrete example. My question is about what you can and can't do with generics, which can be clearly seen in the last line of the question. However your answer focused more on the particular case of sum/cumsum and much less on the actual general-case question. This is not spam at all :)

Comment: "much less on the actual general-case question" look at the 3rd non-code paragraph

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution for this in other languages (Haskell and Scala are best-known ones), which is likely to be added in Kotlin eventually: type classes. See https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/pull/87 for the (non-final) proposal to add them to Kotlin.

Until they are added, you can do something similar manually:

```
interface Adder<T> {
    fun add(x: T, y: T): T
}

object IntAdder : Adder<Int> {
    fun add(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
}
// similar for other types

// definition of cumulativeSum
fun <T> cumulativeSum(list: List<T>, adder: Adder<T>): List<T> = ...

// call
cumulativeSum(listOf(1,2,3), IntAdder)
```

The part type classes solve is that you won't need to pass the `adder` parameter manually, instead the compiler will determine it based on `T`.